# Gremlin: Returning valueMap/projected properties from group by query

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, amazon-neptune

Let's say I have two types of vertices, parents and children. I want to be able to query for all parent vertices and have all the children grouped by their associated parent along with properties for each child. Assume parents have multiple children and children can have only 1 parent. Parent will always have the parent label, but the children can have various different labels.

So right now if I do

`g.V().hasLabel('parent').group().by(__.inE().outV()).toList()`

I get back:

```
[{v[Child_A]: [v[Parent_A]], v[Child_B]: [v[Parent_B]]}]
```

What I want is the opposite hierachy along with the value map/projected values of the child, so for example:

```
[Parent_A: Child_A1: {properties}, Child_A2: {properties}], [Parent_B: Child_B1: {properties]
```

Using python gremlin with Neptune if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your desired output, I think this what you looking for:

```
g.V().hasLabel('parent').group()
   .by(__.values('name'))
   .by(__.in_().group().by(__.values('name')).by(__.valueMap(true)))
```

Comment: This works although it should be "__.in_()", and also "__.valueMap()"

Comment: Oh the underscores didnt show in my above comment due to stackoverflow formatting, but there should be one before the valuemap as well